# Form submit create pdf and save data to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I want to register a person i get the details of the person and there is two buttons when click register button i need to store details to database and when click create button need to generate a pdf.data insertion done no matter but generating pdf not working.when i call create pdf button seperately that code work fine i cannot find  why this is not working

```
<?php 
include("DBConfig/Db_connection.php");//make connection here
include("libs/fpdf.php");  
if(isset($_POST['register']))  
{

    $url='/User_managemet/';
    $todir = 'attachments/';
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'], $todir . basename($_FILES['attachments']['name'] ) );
    $target_file=$url.$todir . basename($_FILES['attachments']['name'] ); 

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $serviceNumber=$_POST['serviceNumber'];
    $designation=$_POST['designation'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $workStation=$_POST['workStation'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];
    $filepath=$target_file;





    if(isset($_POST['crm']))
    {
        $crm='true';
        $crmStatus='New';
    }
    else
    {
        $crm='false';
        $crmStatus='Omit';
    }


    if(isset($_POST['bss']))
    {
        $bss='true';
        $bssStatus='New';
    }
    else
    {
        $bss='false';
        $bssStatus='Omit';
    }


    if(isset($_POST['oss']))
    {
        $oss='true';
        $ossStatus='New';
    }
    else
    {
        $oss='false';
        $ossStatus='Omit';
    }
    $reason=$_POST['reason'];





    $insert_user="INSERT INTO `user`(`serviceNumber`,
    `userName`, `designation`, `dateOfTermination`, 
    `workStation`, `reason`, `attachments`,
    `crm`, `oss`, `bss`,
    `CRM_Status`, `OSS_Status`, `BSS_Status`, 
    `moreInfo`) VALUES ('$serviceNumber','$name','$designation','$date','$workStation','$reason',
    '$filepath','$crm','$oss','$bss','$crmStatus','$ossStatus','$bssStatus','$msg')";


    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_user);
    if(!$result) 
    {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Please try again!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Record details submitted succsesfully!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }



}
else if(isset($_POST['pdf']))
{   
    //here i need to call createpdf.php 

}
else
{}
```

> when click pdf button i need generatepdf that code work fine seperately when i run that independtly n i have trid adding the full code in button click also no any error nothing shows plese help me i also tried using ajax.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the [PDFTemplate](https://github.com/Kommune3/PDFTemplate) library. It simply creates PDF documents from Open Document files (.odt). It's free and really easy to use. You can even add Placeholders to your document and get them filled out by the library.

Comment: As is, this really doesn't answer the querent's question. While the reference library may in fact be a valid solution, it would be better if you provided additional information as to how the querent would use/call the library from within a PHP file as requested below.